# Creating last observation flags for grouped data with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I've searched and found lots of solutions that come close but don't quite answer my question.

I want a function that will add 0/1 flags to data, indicating the last observation per unit. The data are grouped by unit and by the kind of test that was done.

I want to use dplyr and have the following attempt, but the second `mutate_` call is wrong.

```
getLastObsFlag <- function(data, id="subject", time="studyday", test="test"){
  data <- arrange_(data, id, test, time) %>%
    mutate_(lastObsFlag = 0) %>%
    group_by_(id, test) %>%
    mutate_(lastObsFlag = replace(time, n(), 1))

  as.data.frame(data)
}

# Restructure pbcseq from the survival package
junk <- gather(pbcseq, test, value, 12:18)
# That just loaded reshape2 and plyr, so unload them
unloadNamespace("reshape2")
unloadNamespace("plyr")
getLastObsFlag(junk, id="id", time="day", test="test")
```

The call to `n()` throws an error: `Error in dplyr::n() : This function should not be called directly`

I've read this is an issue with having plyr attached as well as dplyr (tho I expected using `dplyr::n()` to overcome that). I checked and plyr is `loaded via a namespace (and not attached)`. I used `unloadNamespace` to remove it (and reshape2), but still get the same error message.

I'd be grateful of any pointers. I'm not attached to `n()`, so an alternative solution would be fine.

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dmhelp_0.5         brglm_0.5-9        profileModel_0.5-9 dplyr_0.4.3        tidyr_0.2.0        gbm_2.1.1          lattice_0.20-33   
[8] survival_2.38-3   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0     assertthat_0.1  MASS_7.3-44     grid_3.2.2      R6_2.1.1        DBI_0.3.1       magrittr_1.5    stringi_0.5-5  
 [9] lazyeval_0.1.10 tools_3.2.2     stringr_1.0.0
```

Comment: I've just tried a few variants on what I think you suggest, but get the same error message (with plyr still not attached or loaded). Please clarify

Comment: Can you try the solution posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `interp` from `library(lazyeval)`.

```
library(lazyeval)
getLastObsFlag <- function(data, id="subject", time="studyday", test="test"){
       data <- arrange_(data, id, test, time) %>%
                    mutate_(lastObsFlag = 0) %>%
                    group_by_(id, test) %>%
                    mutate_(.dots=list(lastObsFlag = interp(~replace(lastObsFlag,
                                               n(), 1))))
      as.data.frame(data)
   }
```

Upon testing

```
head(getLastObsFlag(junk, id="id", time="day", test="test"),25)[c('id', 'test', 'lastObsFlag')]
#  id     test lastObsFlag
#1   1     bili           0
#2   1     bili           1
#3   1     chol           0
#4   1     chol           1
#5   1  albumin           0
#6   1  albumin           1
#7   1 alk.phos           0
#8   1 alk.phos           1
#9   1      ast           0
#10  1      ast           1
#11  1 platelet           0
#12  1 platelet           1
#13  1  protime           0
#14  1  protime           1
#15  2     bili           0
#16  2     bili           0
#17  2     bili           0
#18  2     bili           0
#19  2     bili           0
#20  2     bili           0
#21  2     bili           0
#22  2     bili           0
#23  2     bili           1
#24  2     chol           0
#25  2     chol           0
```

Comment: Not quite... it breaks when we get to the second patient `head(getLastObsFlag(junk, id="id", time="day"), 25)`

Comment: Thanks, didn't check it properly.  Let me check the data again.

Comment: @harrys I think there is a flaw in your function.  You are replacing only the last observation of 'time' with 1.  Instead I think you want `lastObsFlag` to replaced by 1.

Comment: @harrys I updated the post.  Can you check if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! The only change I've made is to call `lazyeval::interp`. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

We can add a variable to the entire data frame with `ifelse` and a `dplyr`window function inside `mutate`.

`junk <- junk %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(day) %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(min_rank(desc(day))!=1,0,1))`

testing results...

```
 id futime status trt      age sex day ascites hepato spiders edema stage     test   value flag
1   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f   0       1      1       1     1     4     bili   14.50    0
2   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f   0       1      1       1     1     4     chol  261.00    0
3   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f   0       1      1       1     1     4  albumin    2.60    0
4   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f   0       1      1       1     1     4 alk.phos 1718.00    0
5   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f   0       1      1       1     1     4      ast  138.00    0
6   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f   0       1      1       1     1     4 platelet  190.00    0
7   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f   0       1      1       1     1     4  protime   12.20    0
8   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f 192       1      1       1     1     4     bili   21.30    1
9   1    400      2   1 58.76523   f 192       1      1       1     1     4     chol      NA    1
10  1    400      2   1 58.76523   f 192       1      1       1     1     4  albumin    2.94    1
```

Comment: I feel like this should be even easier -- just use `mutate(lastObsFlag=(row_number() == n()))`.  (The flag comes out as boolean, which seems to me to be preferable to a 0/1).

Comment: When I wrap this in a function with 2 levels of grouping (id and test), it returns the wrong thing and I don't yet see why...

Comment: I tested my answer in your function and with the additional grouping. It works as expected, but only if I use nse dplyr methods (`mutate` rather than `mutate_`). When using the `mutate_` eval method, I get every `lastObsFlag` = 1, regardless of day. I am not sure why either.